# Error occurred while analyzing the page using Google PageSpeed Insights

Tags: google-developer-tools

I am getting an error while trying to analyze my site using Google PageSpeed Insights. Site Url is http://www.budgettours.co.in/himachal/
I am getting message

> An error occurred while fetching or analyzing the page

I am using this link to analyze https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Answer (score 0):

You have too many resources loading on page load. The Render limit is 200. 
You can also try to test your site with [think with Google](https://testmysite.thinkwithgoogle.com/)